# Dynamically add button to Kendo UI Grid MVC

Tags: button, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, runtime

i created a simple web app in .net MVC that contains a simple input textbox and a grid (showing some DB data).

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Z.ViewModels.ZViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Number);
        columns.Bound(c => c.AddedDate);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProcessingMessageText);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProcessedDate).

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
        .PageSize(20)
    )
        )
```

Now i need to add another feature to this page ... if there is no value (" ") in ProcessedDate display a Button with som custom functionality (call an action from controller with parameter from Number column), else display the value.
Is this possible ?

I tried something like this`ClientTemplate("# if (ProcessingMessageText =='') {#  <button>do stuff</button> #} else if (ProcessingMessageText !='') {# ProcessedDate <#}# ");
        }).Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))` but it didnt worked.

I have a function to change the rows color ... but i dont know how to  access the column values...

```
 function onDataBound(e) {


        var grid = this;
        var currentRecords = grid.dataSource.view();

        for (var i = 0; i < currentRecords.length; i++) {
            //currentRecords[i] is the current dataItem
            if (currentRecords[i].ProcessingMessageText == "Finished") {
                grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentRecords[i].uid + "']").addClass("rowSucess");
          }

             if (currentRecords[i].ProcessingMessageText == "Sent") {
                var row= grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentRecords[i].uid + "']").addClass("rowSent");


            }

            else if (currentRecords[i].ProcessingMessageText == "Error") {
                grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentRecords[i].uid + "']").addClass("rowError");


            }


        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a template column that calls your MVC action and passes a parameter(number) is fairly straight forward. This example creates a bootstrap button to call my controller and pass it the parameter named 'number' using kendo hash tag syntax. Carefull with the single vs double quotes.:

```
columns.Template(t => { }).Title(string.Empty).Width(40)
    .ClientTemplate(@"<a href='" + Url.Action("MyAction","MyController") + "?number=#= Number#' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' title='Modify this item'>Edit</a>");
```

You would need to add your if statement to show the date if the field is not empty, otherwise show the button.